# Cruzamento de valores em array

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho um valor **X** e tenho um **array** com vários valores.

Gostaria de pesquisar todos os valores iguais **e menores, que entrariam em uma combinação** que **suas soma** dariam o valor **X**.

---

**Exemplo:**

Array (no cenário real, milhares de valores):

```
$dados = array('0.10','0.20','0.30','0.50',
               '3.00','3.30','4.00','5.00',
               '1.00','1.10','2.00','2.20');
```

Supondo que o valor de **X** é `0.50`, as possíveis somas seriam:

- `0.20 + 0.30`
- `0.50`

Supondo que o valor de **X** é `1.10`, as possíveis somas seriam:

- `0.10 + 0.20 + 0.30 + 0.50`
- `0.10 + 1.00`
- `1.10`

Supondo que o valor de **X** é `1.40`, as possíveis somas seriam:

- `0.10 + 0.30 + 1.00`
- `0.10 + 0.20 + 1.10`
- `0.30 + 1.10`

---

**O que eu gostaria de saber**, são formas de como realizar esse cruzamento, preferencialmente com funções nativas.

---

*Tenho já minhas ideias de como fazer, mas se eu postar, poderá "viciar" a ideia de vocês, e acabarem indo pelo mesmo caminho que estou pensando, e se eu estiver errado, acabo atrapalhando.*

Comment: Apenas para confirmar, embora seu exemplo mostra apenas 2 valores por soma, a combinação poderá envolver QUALQUER quantidade de elementos, certo? Ex: se o valor X for 2.10, os elementos poderiam ser por exemplo 0+10 + 0.20 + 0.30 + 0.50 + 1.00 = 2.10 ou 1.00 + 1.10 = 2.10 ou ainda 0.10 + 2.00 = 2.10, etc.?

Comment: @RogérioDec exatamente! Terei uma linhas com milhares de valores! Adicionei mais 1 exemplo.

Comment: Estou tentando entender, seria somar todos valores menores em um unico, ou somar um a um destes menores com o `X`?

Comment: Seriam todas as possíveis combinações de soma, que dariam o valor de X.

Comment: Para milhares de valores não me parece que seja possivel de obter todas as combinações, pois se forem mil valores as combinações possíveis são `1000!`. Mas para algo não muito grande dá para fazer [assim](https://ideone.com/0Rb49t)

Comment: @Isac não entendi seu código, ele não tem o valor referência para as somas. E também não entendi "pois se forem mil valores as combinações possíveis são 1000"... As possíveis combinações iniciariam com os valores menores que X, já que, o valor máximo é X. Com esses valores, teria que testar todas as possíveis combinações que dão exatamente o valor de X.

Comment: Teoricamente eu pegaria 1 por 1, iria somando somando numa sequencia ordenada, até atingir o valor de X ou se ultrapassar, a combinação já não é válida. Aí começa novamente, 1 por 1 e pula o valor da sequencia, e continua somando os próximos, até ver se dá o valor de X. Assim sequencialmente até testar todas as possibilidades de soma que darão X. Seriam sim, milhões de cálculos.

Comment: "se forem mil valores as combinações possíveis são 1000!" (mil fatorial) Faça na calculadora para ver o número que estamos a falar. São todas essas as combinações que precisam de ser analisadas a ver se dão a soma que pretende. Naturalmente muitas delas podem ser cortadas sem serem totalmente analisadas, mas mesmo assim é muita coisa. O valor referência para a soma é passado na função `combinacoesParaObjetivo` como segundo parametro (no exemplo o `1.1`)

Comment: Não seriam mais? Por que vamos contar pelo início do array: Eu começo somando o valor do `array[0], array[1], array[2],...`... se não for igual a X, então começaria novamente `array[0], array[2], array[3],...`... realmente seriam MUITOS "testes"...

Comment: A ideia é o seguinte: tenho por exemplo 10mil notas, e no valor delas, preciso encontrar todas que tem o valor de `100,51`, ou todas as combinações de valores menor, que a soma é igual a `100,51`.

Comment: Acho que vocẽ não está a visualizar quanto é `1000!` Tem [aqui nesta página](http://justinwhite.com/big-calc/1000.html) só para a diversão :D. Por isso sim tem umas "quantas" combinações a testar

Comment: Agora entendi! hahaha... esse "!" é proposital! Eu nem sabia o que isso significava! rs Cara, então não existe essa possibilidade ?

Comment: então só para que possa entender melhor, você quer que retorne um vetor só com as combinações somada ao valor passado? Em um exemplo mais simples, `A = 100; B = [...valores]; X = [A + B[0], A + B[1], A + B[2]];`, claro que o array em X seria gerado pelo algoritimo, mas ideia é para entender se eu entendi a sua necessidade

Comment: Isso. É que imprimir ou retornar em array tanto faz, porque terei outras manipulações depois. Mas sim, seriam todas as combinações possíveis que a soma dá X. Igual nos exemplos que dei, o retorno terá que conter quais são as combinações de os valores do array, que somados dão X.

Comment: Para todos que quiserem discutir a pergunta, criei um [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80326/cruzamento-de-valores-em-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demorei 8 horas para desenvolver o algoritmo, mas valeu pelo desafio.

Aqui está o código:

```
<?php
$total = 3.60; // valor total a ser testado
echo "Para um total de $total:\n\n";
$dados = array('0.10','0.20','0.30','0.50',
               '3.00','3.30','4.00','5.00',
               '1.00','1.10','2.00','2.20');
foreach ($dados as $d) 
    $dadosf[] = floatval($d); // cria array paralelo em float para facilitar

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dados) - 1; $i++) 
    $base[]=array($i); // cria os primeiros valores de base

for ($n = 2;$n < sizeof($dados); $n++) {
    foreach ($base as $i => $b1) { // soma os números de base
        $soma_base[$i]=0;
        foreach ($b1 as $b2) {
            $soma_base[$i] += $dadosf[$b2];
        }
    }
    $base2 = [];
    for ($b = 0; $b < sizeof($base); $b++) {
        $u = sizeof($base[$b])-1; // último elemento da base
        for ($p = $base[$b][$u] + 1; $p < sizeof($dados); $p++) {
            if (number_format($soma_base[$b] + $dadosf[$p], 3) == 
                number_format($total, 3)) { 
            // *** encontrou combinação da soma ***             
                echo 'Combinação ' . ++$c . ': ';
                for ($d = 0; $d <= $u; $d++) { 
                    echo $dados[$base[$b][$d]] . ' + ';
                }
                echo $dados[$p] . ' = ' . $total . "\n";
            }
            $base2[] = $base[$b];
            $base2[sizeof($base2)-1][] = $p;
        }
    }
    $base = $base2;
}
```

Neste exemplo, usando `3.6` como valor a comparar, o resultado será:

```
Para um total de 3.6:

Combinação 1: 0.30 + 3.30 = 3.6
Combinação 2: 0.10 + 0.20 + 3.30 = 3.6
Combinação 3: 0.10 + 0.50 + 3.00 = 3.6
Combinação 4: 0.30 + 1.10 + 2.20 = 3.6
Combinação 5: 0.50 + 1.10 + 2.00 = 3.6
Combinação 6: 0.10 + 0.20 + 0.30 + 3.00 = 3.6
Combinação 7: 0.10 + 0.20 + 1.10 + 2.20 = 3.6
Combinação 8: 0.10 + 0.30 + 1.00 + 2.20 = 3.6
Combinação 9: 0.10 + 0.50 + 1.00 + 2.00 = 3.6
Combinação 10: 0.20 + 0.30 + 1.10 + 2.00 = 3.6
Combinação 11: 0.10 + 0.20 + 0.30 + 1.00 + 2.00 = 3.6
```

O código está em https://ideone.com/BCyi6v#stdin

A base da lógica é uma análise combinatória. Usando uma matriz fictícia abaixo de, por exemplo, 5 elementos, as combinações deveriam ser as seguintes:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Elementos   | 1,2,3,4,5 |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Combinações |           |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Nível 2     | Nível 3   | Nível 4 | Nível 5   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1,2         | 1,2,3     | 1,2,3,4 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1,3         | 1,2,4     | 1,2,3,5 |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1,4         | 1,2,5     | 1,3,4,5 |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1,5         | 1,3,4     | 2,3,4,5 |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2,3         | 1,3,5     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2,4         | 1,4,5     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2,5         | 2,3,4     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 3,4         | 2,3,5     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 3,5         | 2,4,5     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 4,5         | 3,4,5     |         |           |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Perceba que cada nível posterior contém uma derivação dos elementos do nível anterior.

Comment: Caraca bicho! Sensacional! Vou olhar com MUITA calma, tentar entender e perguntar os pontos que não entender. Com certeza terei dúvidas, então já vou criar um chat.

Comment: [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80326/cruzamento-de-valores-em-array)

Comment: Deu certo? Se sim, por favor aprovar a resposta e positivar.

Comment: Rogério ainda não terminei de testar... em vista sim... só falta trazer o número igual também...

Comment: "trazer o número igual", você quer comparar um número simples do array com o número que está testando? Ex: se no array tiver 1.20, 3.90, 4.70 e você estiver buscando por exemplo 3.90 ele deve acusar também, isso? Mas isso é simples, só adicionar um código fazendo uma comparação de 1 para 1 antes.

Comment: Sim... Não tive tempo pra pegar nisso ainda. Como há um limite por conta de comparações, então não terei nem como usar. Mas foi bacana o "desafio". Obrigado!

Comment: Desculpe, mas qual limite?

Comment: Coloquei um array com 60 valores, a última combinação que ele consegue é : 889, e dá erro de falta de memória `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\_test\cruzaarray.php on line 55`. Como no meu caso pode chegar até milhares de registros e 80 já esgota a memória, então sem condições. Teria que ser outra lógica, o que acredito que não tenha por conta das combinações, correto!?

Comment: Eu fiz o código pensando em minimizar o consumo de memória. Dá para diminuir um pouco mais retirando o array `$dadosf[]` e substituindo as referências dele por `floatval($dados[...`, mas isso não resolverá o problema para tão grande quantidade de combinações. Neste post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml) há referências para aumentar o limite de memória do PHP, dependendo do servidor que você usa. Mas acho que o ideal neste caso seria usar um cache em disco.

Comment: É, em memória não tem como, por isso desisti. Mas agora usar cache em disco, nunca tinha escutado isso. Vou dar uma pesquisada! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz pelo menos em saber que a lógica funciona, portanto o desafio (bem menor) agora é fazer isso caber na memória. Quando falo em cache, não é algo nativo do php, me refiro a fazer leituras e gravações dos arrays em disco, ou seja, mexer no código nas área mais críticas e fazer leituras em disco ao invés de deixar tudo na RAM.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80564/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-rbz).

Comment: Opa, mandei uma pergunta no chat, você chegou a receber o aviso?

Answer (score 1):

### EDIÇÃO:

> Esta solução só será viável para um número limitado de itens, não pelo
>   espaço, mas pelo tempo de processamento devido ao grande número de
>   combinações possíveis.
>
> Para saber quantas combinações poderão ser encontradas entre todos os
>   itens a serem comparados, esta é a fórmula:
>
> [image: 1]]
>
> Então, se o array `$dados` tiver por exemplo apenas 30 itens itens, o número de combinações possíveis seria `2^30 - 1` = 1.073.741.823; se forem 100 itens = 
>   1,26765E+30!!!
>
> Também pode-se calcular quantas combinações são possíveis por nível, isto é, combinação com 2 números juntos, 3 números, etc. Neste caso a fórmula é:
>
> [image: 2]]
>
> ... onde `n` = número total de itens e `k` = nível atual. 
>   Ex: para saber quantas combinações são possíveis numa sequência de 5 números, dentro do nível 2: `5! / (2! * (5 - 2)!)` = 10. Ou seja, se fizermos uma comparação para a sequência `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, no nível 2 da comparação `(1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 5, 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, 3 4, 3 5, 4 5)` = 10 itens.

Esta segunda resposta resolve a questão de limitação de RAM: MySql!

Se na primeira resposta eu demorei 8 horas, não vou dizer o quanto gastei nessa, senão vão pensar que eu sou louco!... rsrsrs

Recriei todo o algoritmo de forma que os grandes arrays sejam usados em tabelas do banco de dados.

Desta forma, o número de combinações fica virtualmente ilimitado, apenas dependendo do espaço em disco.

Vale a pena ressaltar que embora esta segunda abordagem resolva o problema de estouro de RAM, a contrapartida é que ele ficará absurdamente mais lento. Quero dizer, se for fazer o processo com por exemplo 100 valores, ponha o computador para trabalhar e vá dormir... :)

Confira um exemplo funcionando em MySql neste link: http://sandbox.sortemaniasudoeste.com.br/wp-content/php/comb.php

Em resumo, para funcionar, basta:

1. Criar um banco de dados Mysql (vazio)
2. Modificar os dados do banco no código fonte
3. Modificar o valor a testar e o número de elementos (esta parte você substituirá por sua tabela original)

Abaixo o código:

```
<?php
$total = 3.6; // preencher com valor total a ser testado
$num_dados = 12; // preencher com o total de números que serão gerados para teste

$time_start = microtime(true); // cronometra o tempo total de processamento

// ****************** CONEXÃO COM BANCO DE DADOS **************************
$servername = "localhost"; // nome do servidor
$username = "root"; // nome do usuario
$password = ""; // senha
$dbname = "comb"; // nome do banco de dados

$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$db) {
    die("Falha na conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

cria_tabela($db, 'dados', 1);
cria_tabela($db, 'base',  2, 'int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL');
cria_tabela($db, 'resultados',  1, 'varchar(10000)');

gera_dados($db, $num_dados); // gera x registros de dados float

//******************** ALGORITMO ***********************

$cont_combina = 0;
echo "Para um total de $total:\n\n";

// carrega dados no array $dados --------------------

$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM dados');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $dados[] = $row['valor'];

// testa se existe o valor (sem soma) dentro de $dados
if (in_array($total, $dados))
    echo "1 nível\nCombinação " . ++$cont_combina . ': ' . number_format($total, 2) . ' = ' . number_format($total, 2) . "\n\n";

// cria os primeiros valores de base-----------------
$key1 = 0; $key2 = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dados) - 1; $i++) { // base são sempre a soma dos valores anteriores exceto 1 à direita que será comparado
    $sql = "INSERT INTO base (key1, key2, valor) VALUES ($key1, 0, $i)";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao inserir registro na tabela 'base'");
    $key1++;
}

// processa as combinações gerais --------------------
for ($nivel = 1;$nivel < sizeof($dados) - 1; $nivel++) {
    echo "-------------------------\n" . ($nivel+1) . " níveis (";
    printf("%d", $nivel * 100 / (sizeof($dados) - 1));
    echo "%)\n";

// soma os números de base-----------------------------
    cria_tabela($db, 'soma_base', 1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO soma_base (key1, valor)
              SELECT base.key1, SUM(dados.valor) FROM base 
                INNER JOIN dados ON base.valor = dados.key1 
                GROUP BY base.key1";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao gerar registros na tabela 'soma_base'");

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM soma_base ORDER BY key1 DESC LIMIT 1");
    if (!$soma_base = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) die ("erro leitura tabela 'soma_base'");
    $ult_combinacao = $soma_base['key1'];

    // análise combinatória -----------------------------
    cria_tabela($db, 'base_ant', 2, 'int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL');
    $key1_base_ant = 0;

    for ($combinacao = 0; $combinacao < $ult_combinacao; $combinacao++) {
        // acha valor do último elemento da base atual para calcular o próximo
        $result2 = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT count(*) AS tot_elem_key1 FROM base WHERE key1 = ' . $combinacao);  // total elementos key1
        $base2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $tot_elem_key1 = $base2['tot_elem_key1'] - 1;

        $result2 = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base WHERE key1 = ' . $combinacao . ' AND key2 < 9999999999 ORDER BY key1, key2 DESC');  //acha último elemento da base
        if (!$base2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) die ("não achou último elemento");
        // $p = ponteiro para valor o valor a ser comparado. Ex: soma dos valores base + valor indicado pelo ponteiro
        for ($p = $base2['valor'] + 1; $p < sizeof($dados); $p++) { // pega o valor do último elemento da base atual + 1 (próximo elemento)
            $result3 = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM soma_base WHERE key1 = ' . $combinacao);  // acha soma deste nível
            if (!$soma_base = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) die ("não achou soma base");
//            if ($soma_base['valor'] >= $total) break;
            if (number_format($soma_base['valor'] + $dados[$p], 4) == number_format($total, 4)) { // *** encontrou combinação da soma ***
                // mostra combinação encontrada  -------------------
                echo 'Combinação ' . ++$cont_combina . ': ';
                $d = 0;
                $result5 = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base WHERE key1 = ' . $combinacao);
                $numeros = []; // armazena resultados num array para gravar em tabela
                while ($base5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5) and $d <= $tot_elem_key1) {
                    echo number_format($dados[$base5['valor']], 2) . ' + ';
                    $numeros[] = floatval($dados[$base5['valor']]);
                    $d++;
                }
                echo number_format($dados[$p], 2) . ' = ' . number_format($total, 2) . "\n";
                $numeros[] = floatval($dados[$p]);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO resultados (key1, valor) VALUES ($cont_combina, '" . serialize($numeros) . "')"; // grava resultado encontrado
                mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao inserir registro na tabela 'resultados'");
            }

            // transfere base para base_ant  -------------------
            $result4 = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base WHERE key1 = ' . $combinacao);
            while ($base4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
                $key2 = $base4['key2'];
                $valor = $base4['valor'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO base_ant (key1, key2, valor) VALUES ($key1_base_ant, $key2, $valor)";
                mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao inserir registro na tabela 'base_ant'");
                $key2++;
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO base_ant (key1, key2, valor) VALUES ($key1_base_ant, $key2, $p)";
            $key1_base_ant++;
            mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao inserir registro 2 na tabela 'base_ant'");
        }
    }
    mysqli_query($db, "DROP TABLE base") or die(mysqli_error($db));
    mysqli_query($db, "RENAME TABLE base_ant TO base") or die(mysqli_error($db));
}

mysqli_close($db);
echo "\n(100%)\n";
$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;
echo "Tempo total de execução: " . number_format($execution_time, 2) . " Minutos\n";

return;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function cria_tabela($db, $tabela, $campos_chave, $tipo_valor = "float UNSIGNED NOT NULL") {
    $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tabela";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tabela (";
    if ($campos_chave > 0) $sql .=   "key1 int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL";
    if ($campos_chave > 1) $sql .= ", key2 int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL";
    if ($campos_chave > 0) $sql .=   ", ";
    $sql .= "valor $tipo_valor)";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nNão foi possível criar tabela '$tabela'"); 
    if ($campos_chave > 0) { // cria índice
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE $tabela ADD PRIMARY KEY (key1";
        if ($campos_chave > 1) $sql .=   ",key2";
        $sql .=")";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nNão foi possível criar índice para tabela '$tabela'");
    }
}

function gera_dados($db, $num) {
    for ($i = 1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dados (key1, valor) VALUES (" . ($i - 1) . ", " . ($i / 10) . ")";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "\nFalha ao inserir registro na tabela 'dados'");  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment:  Fenomenal cara! Demais! Te respondi lá no chat!

Comment: Criei uma revisão no código, pois como o `mysqli_query` carrega todos os dados da tabela em RAM, um trecho anterior com `SELECT * FROM base` estava dando estouro de memória quando a tabela `base` atingia alguns milhões de registros. Creio que desta forma agora esteja melhor. 
Também acho que dá pra melhorar a questão da performance, mas isso exige um estudo mais profundo. O importante é que agora funciona sem limites de itens.

Comment: Teria uma forma de calcular o tempo previsto de finalização?

Comment: Deve ter, mas isso deveria ser feito baseado num estudo matemático de análise combinatória, baseada no algoritmo atual, além de analisar o tempo de resposta entre as comunicações com o banco, que são variáveis. Mas imagino que dependendo da quantidade de itens a serem analisados e consequentemente a quantidade de combinações, isso pode demorar dias ou semanas... ainda assim é mais rápido do que se fosse feito 'na mão', rsrsrs.

Comment: A fórmula para saber quantas combinações são possíveis dentro de "x" itens é: `2^x - 1`. Por exemplo, se `$dados` tiver 30 itens, então 2^30 - 1 = 1.073.741.823 de combinações possíveis!

Comment: Cara, é um rebento de processamento! Muito bruto!

Comment: Eu diria que dependendo do número de itens, isto ficaria inviável. Por exemplo, para 1000 itens, daria 1,0715E+301 de combinações... acho que nem tem tantos átomos no universo, rsrsrs.

Comment: Foi o que o Isac disse nos comentários, e passou esse link [Factorial 1000](http://justinwhite.com/big-calc/1000.html) aburdo! hahaha

Comment: Embora talvez este trabalho todo se transforme em algo inviável, ainda assim deixei uma edição na resposta para alertar sobre estas conclusões, incluindo fórmulas para chegar aos totais, caso alguém futuramente busque algo semelhante. Mesmo assim, valeu pelo "desafio"!

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço php, porém a lógica por trás é simples.

Uma das possíveis maneiras de fazer isso é, dentro de uma estrutura de repetição ter uma variavel de soma(ex: soma), cujo objetivo é se igualar ao valor pretendido (valor informado por voce) e, em forma de loop, obter de dentro do vetor o maior valor possivel que quando somado na variavel de controle "soma" não ultrapassará o valor pretendido. isso será executado ate que a variavel soma se iguale ao valor pretendido ou ela ultrapasse o valor pretendido.

Ex:
valores no vetor -> 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 2.0, 2,5;

Digamos o valor pretendido é 4,0.

Dentro de uma estrutura de repetição, terei a variável "soma".

A primeira vez que a estrutura de repetição for executada, será adicionado o maior número possível para que a variável soma não ultrapasse 4,0 (2,5).

Nesse momento soma = 2,5

A próxima execução da estrutura de repetição adicionará 1,0, pois se for adicionado 2,0 ou 2,5 o valor ultrapassará 4,0.

Nesse momento soma = 3,5

A próxima execução adicionará o valor 0,5, já que é o maior valor que quando adicionado à variável "soma" não provocará o "estouro" do valor.

Nesse momento soma = 4,0

Valor pretendido atingido.

Comment: Filipe, eu fiz um teste exatamente nessa lógica, de ir somando. Mas não funciona. Se eu somar sequencial, não terei todas as possíveis combinações. O negócio é realmente cruzar todos os dados, também nessa ideia de soma.

Answer (score -3):

Pensei no seguinte:

```
$dados = array('0.10', '0.20', '0.30', '0.50',
                   '3.00', '3.30', '4.00', '5.00',
                   '1.00', '1.10', '2.00', '2.20');
    $valorX = 5.00;
    $nc = count($dados);

    for($a = 0; $a < $nc; $a++){
        for($b = 0; $b < $nc; $b++){
           if ( $a < $nc) {
                // verifica se os valores escolhidos somados são iguais ao valor escolhido
                if ($dados[$a] + $dados[$b] == $valorX) {
                    echo 'valor 1 = ' . $dados[$a] . ' / valor 2 = ' . $dados[$b] . '<br>';
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cara, está cheio de erros. Você conseguiu reproduzir aí?

Comment: Arrumei, agora está certo.

Comment: Leandro, não está funcionando. Ele poderá ter mais que 2 valores, e também deve trazer todas as possíveis combinações. Veja o seu script, tente reproduzir os exemplos que postei. Se bater, aí funcionou! Mas agradeço a tentativa :)

Comment: Refiz o código (rs), e agora ele está verificando todos itens do array (só vim entender o seu objetivo agora).

Comment: Logo de cara vi que está errado. Você trava 2 valores. Faz como eu disse, testa meus exemplos, tenta reproduzi-los, assim você vê se está correto.