# Abrir e fechar o código ou usar variável?

Tags: php, html, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

### Dois *scripts* com mesmos resultado:

#### Exemplo 1:

```
<?php

...códigos PHP acima...

$tabela = '<table>';
$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<th> Valor1 </th>';
$tabela .= '<th> Valor2 </th>';
$tabela .= '<th> Valor3 </th>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td>' . $valor1 . '</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>' . $valor2 . '</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>' . $valor3 . '</td>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
$tabela .= '</table>';

echo $tabela;

...códigos PHP abaixo...

?>
```

#### Exemplo 2:

```
<?php

...códigos PHP acima...
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Valor1 </th>
    <th> Valor2 </th>
    <th> Valor3 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <?= $valor1 ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $valor2 ?> </td>
    <td> <?= $valor3 ?> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?
...códigos PHP abaixo...

?>
```

---

Gostaria de saber se existem, e quais seriam, as **vantagens e desvantagens** entre os exemplos acima.

**Por exemplo**: penso que tratar tudo em uma variável para depois imprimir, iria ocupar mais memória e processamento, pois há a concatenação e espaço em memória (principalmente se considerarmos em grandes laços).

---

Ponto que me levantou a questão:

Erro por excesso de cálculos

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

[Cruzamento de valores em array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315869/cruzamento-de-valores-em-array)

Comment: Downvoter, comente o porque do -1, assim poderei melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Para pensar: e você acha que no segundo exemplo o HTML ficará armazenado onde, já que no primeiro seria em memória?

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal. Seria o caso da memória da variável, que esgota: exemplo `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)`. Seriam as 2 formas iguais? Agora me confundiu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro envolve mais processamento, é um código PHP sendo interpretado e processado para gerar um texto que será enviado ao servidor (possivelmente). O segundo já é considerado o texto a ser enviado apenas invocando o processador do PHP em algumas partes, e tem um custo muito menor (para processar o texto).

Então o primeiro tem o custo do *buffer* do texto do HTML como um todo e o *buffer* de manipulação da *string*.

De forma geral o segundo é mais legível. O segundo costuma ser usado mais como um *template* da página a ser renderizada onde só algumas lacunas são preenchidas por processamento, que dá muito mais trabalho para executar já que tudo precisa ser garantidamente correto, ao contrário do HTML que pode ser mandado até todo errado que é responsabilidade do cliente, possivelmente um navegador web, determinar se está certo ou não.

O primeiro não é comum e só deveria ser usado em casos que seja algo muito complexo a ser processado. Geralmente seria melhor fazer o processamento e depois gerar o texto do HTML.

Ele tende a usar mais memória também porque ocupará no PHP para processar como dados e depois criar o texto final. Mas isso é detalhe de implementação.

Mesmo o PHP tendo *strings* mutáveis ainda assim tende a alocar mais fazendo várias concatenações assim. Não é tão crítico quanto linguagens que trabalham com *strings* imutáveis.

Neste exemplo específico eu optaria pelo segundo (teve época que eu fazia diferente, mas eu estava errado, fazia por gosto e não por necessidade). Há casos que eu poderia optar pelo primeiro. Não que vá fazer uma enorme diferença. Sempre falo que se quer eficiência opte por outra linguagem, PHP te dá facilidade (ou dava), não eficiência.

Só note que estou estimando um pouco as coisas. Consigo ver um cenário que o primeiro possa ser mais eficiente. Não deveria, mas dependendo da arquitetura do PHP é possível, eu só não contaria com isso. De qualquer forma teria que avaliar, mas novamente, se for necessário, a ferramenta é errada.

Esse erro de memória deve ser por outra coisa. Isso por si só não causa este tipo de erro, mas várias outras coisas erradas juntas podem causar o erro em qualquer mínima alocação. É só uma coincidência ocorrer aí, para este caso não faz nem *cosquinha*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Ele tende a usar mais memória também porque ocupará no PHP para processar como dados e depois criar o texto final."... Você diz, que quando "quebro" o script (?><?) estou cortando e iniciando novamente o processo do PHP ou não? Por exemplo: no exemplo1 ele processa tudo em 1x, no exemplo2, ele processa 2x?

Comment: @RBZ O que vem depois de um `?>` vai para o buffer de saída do php (portanto também ocupa memória). Dentro do código php, só vai para o buffer o que você manda dar `echo`.

Comment: @bfavaretto rapaz, agora me complicou mais. Vou ter que ir mais a fundo nesse assunto. Percebi que o pouco que eu tinha ideia, é mais pouco do que eu pensava! rs Mas agradeço! ✌️

Comment: @RBZ é uma preocupação maior do que é um problema.

Answer (score 4):

**Não existe certo e errado aqui**, existem necessidades, no primeiro você salvou tudo em um string e depois jogou para o echo, isso é util se for tratar o valor da variável incluindo o HTML

Agora se a intenção é não fazer nada com valor da variavel e só jogar para o echo o segundo exemplo é bem mais fácil de dar manutenção e entender o seu proprio HTML, mesmo que fosse um loop de `while` que traria resultados e um array ou banco de dados.

Então para concluir, você pode usar qualquer um dos dois, mas o primeiro será útil mesmo se for manipular a `$tabela`, com `DOMDocument`, ou com funções de string como, `substr`, `str_replace`, `preg_replace`, etc.

Agora sobre a memoria, a probabilidade disto ocorrer é raríssima, se ocorreu é porque fez algo muito absurdo, grave mesmo e poderia ocorrer até sem a variável, por exemplo se usar o buffer, como `ob_start` (ou até mesmo sem buffer), devo dizer que se ocorreu é porque fez algo muito de errado, supondo que seu `php.ini` limite para `memory_limit=2MB`, a `string` teria que ser gigante mesmo para conseguir alcançar isto.

Outras situações que podem ocasionar isto é a manipulação de imagens com GD, que é complexa e realmente consome muita memoria, o uso de frameworks pesados (não vou citar nomes, no chat quem tiver interesse sobre o assunto dos frameworks podem me chamar) ou um loop que fica criando variaveis de maneira sem controle algum.

Para irmos aos finalmentes, o problema com memória geralmente esta na forma de como fez e não necessariamente em setar variavel ou exibir direto.

Comment: Realmente não tinha pensado nisso, nas manipulações em `string`, e até o `DOM` num caso de precisar imprimir. É que a pergunta surgiu no caso de exceder o limite, como editei e postei no final. Mas pensando melhor, seria o mesmo espaço.

Comment: @RBZ para exceder a memoria vc tem que ter feito algo gigante, e pode ocorrer até se não for string, tem que ser algo absurdo mesmo, o que costuma exceder memoria é manipulação de muitos dados sem cuidado, do qual vai gerando inumeras variaveis, ou manipular dados complexos, como imagens com GD.

Comment: Entendi. Então nesses casos seriam totalmente irrelevantes. 

Comment: @RBZ editei a resposta.